# Unable to load shared library 'kernel32' or

Tags: docker

Application startup exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'kernel32' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libkernel32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.SnapshotCollector.NativeMethods.

docker file:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/ /core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

Comment: try: 
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
(or)
microsoft/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: kernel32.dll is a Windows dll, so it looks like you're trying to run a Windows program in a Linux container.